# Form select com Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho esse código funcionando, porém gostaria de saber se teria uma maneira mais elegante de escrever o seguinte código na view, através dos forms do Laravel:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
        <label for="marca_id">Selecione a marca deste produto</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="marca_id" required>
        @foreach($marcas as $marca)            
            <option value="{{$marca->id}}">{{$marca->nome}}</option>
        @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Tentei da seguinte maneira:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">            
    {!! Form::label('marca_id', 'Seleciona a marca deste produto', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
    {!! Form::select('marca_id', $marcas, old('marca_id'), ['class' => 'form-control select']) !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

Porém ele retornou as array assim no `SELECT`: `{"nome":"Teste"}` e não exibiu os valores corretos na `value`.

A função create do controller:

```
public function create()
{
    if (! Gate::allows('users_manage')) {
        return abort(401);
    }
    $marcas = MarcaCelular::all('nome');
    return view('celulares.create', compact('marcas'));
}
```

O model MarcaCelular:

```
class MarcaCelular extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        "nome"
    ];

    protected $table = "marcas_celulares";

    public function celulares(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Celular', 'marca_id');
    }

}
```

O model Celular

```
class Celular extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        "modelo", "cor", "marca_id"
    ];

    protected $table = "celulares";

    public function marca_celular(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\MarcaCelular', 'marca_id');
    }

    public function cor(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Cor', 'cor_id');
    }

}
```

Comment: Altera para  $marcas = MarcaCelular::all('nome')->pluck('nome','id');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu `controller` altere:

```
public function create()
{
    if (! Gate::allows('users_manage')) 
    {
        return abort(401);
    }
    $marcas = MarcaCelular::pluck('nome', 'id');
    return view('celulares.create', compact('marcas'));
}
```

esse método `pluck` (que é contido na `Builder` e tambem na classe `Collection`) faz um `array` ***associativo*** da seguinte maneira:

```
[id] = nome
```

seguindo o exemplo do código, tudo que o `Form::select` precisa para gerar o `<select>`.

***Referencias:***

- [Eloquent: Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-collections)
- [Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries)

Comment: Perfeito amigo, era isso mesmo que desejava. Utilizando os Form do Laravel o código fica muito mais limpo. Obrigado de coração!

Comment: Apenas o meu comentário de forma detalhada. É algo similar ao array_column do PHP puro.